# iOS 12, Xcode 10: UIView setNeedsDisplay(_:) seems to be broken

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10, ios12

After updating to Xcode 10 I realized that the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` routine of my custom UIView (class derived from UIView) in my application was called with the wrong `rect`. Indeed it is always called with `rect` being the full frame of the underlying UIView, instead of the `rect` being specified by `setNeedsDisplay(_ rect: CGRect)`.

Here is a code snippet that can be run as a playground, which at least in my setup shows the erroneous behavior described above in a minimalistic setting:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class CustomView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        print("rect = \(rect)")
    }
}

let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = customView
print("test")
customView.setNeedsDisplay(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)))
```

The output I get is

> rect = (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 200.0) 
>   test 
>   rect = (0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 200.0)

The first printed output for rect is the standard full redraw of the view, but the second one after printing "test" yields the problem. The output there is from redrawing due to calling `customView.setNeedsDisplay` before and should be the smaller specified rectangle `(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)`.

So my obvious questions are:

- Can you reproduce this behavior?
- Am I missing something obvious?
- Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this in Xcode 9, 10 & 10.1.

The behaviour has definitely changed between iOS 11 and iOS 12 / 12.1

There's no indication in the documentation or header file that this was intentional.

Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I disagree this is a bug. It is a change in behaviour, but I cannot find any documentation stating that the argument to `setNeedsDisplay(_:)` will be used for the next call to `draw(_:)`.

Comment: The documentation certainly heavily implies that though. For `setNeedsDisplay(_:)`: "Marks the specified rectangle of the receiver as needing to be redrawn" and for `draw(_:)`: "during subsequent drawing operations, the rectangle may specify only part of your view".

Comment: I think this is absolutely essential functionality of `setNeedsDisplay(_ rect: CGRect)`. I also think it is the intended way to do your "partial" view updates. Of course one could call draw directly, but that would break the update design pattern.

Comment: Maybe worth asking on the Apple dev forums and see if anyone from Apple responds.

Comment: Did post it on the Apple developer forums. Let's see.

Comment: This tripped me up too so I've added an answer below that explains the cause and intentionality in case anyone is still looking for the full answer

Answer (score 7):

This is actually intentional with iOS 12's new dynamic backing store feature.

### What is a backing store

A backing store is what stores the drawn view, and that needs memory assigned to do so. That memory amount is dependent on how big the view is as it is essentially a map between colours and pixels.

If you were to draw a grayscale image but the memory has been assigned for the wide colour gamut then that would result in lots of empty assigned memory (gray scale has a lower footprint that RGBA). To get around this the dynamic backing store feature works by drawing the whole content of a view, and THEN working out how much memory it needs rather than assuming everything needs wide colour backing from the start.

The knock on effect of this is that you can't re-draw a smaller sub section of the view as that might then change this store.

### How to get around it

This is a great new feature, but if you really do need to work around it you can disable dynamic backing stores on your view. The way you do that is by explicitly setting the `contentsFormat` property of the views `layer`.

There are three options you can chose which relate to grayscale, RGBA 8bit and RGBA 16 bit (wide colour)

so just call:

```
layer.contentsFormat = .RGBA16Float
```

and your `setNeedsDisplay(_ rect: CGRect)` will start working as expected again

You can read up on the property here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1792104-contentsformat

There's also a great talk from WWDC 18 that explains the new dynamic backing store and (very quietly) mentions this technique

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/?time=1451

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 15